# Error en id (Foreing_key) al guardar lista en Base de Datos WPF C#

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos, wpf, binding

Hola estoy tratando de guardar una lista en la base de datos(ventas)y me da error el Idproducto que extraigo de otra tabla (Producto) 
(parte del XAML)

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="txtIdProducto" 
Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5" SelectedValuePath="IdProducto" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Articulo}" />
                <Run Text="{Binding Compañia}" />
                <Run Text="{Binding Modelo}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Da error es en IdProducto (que es de la tabla producto), ya que he creado un comboBox concatenado para poder ver de que producto se trata y creo que esta cogiendo no el id sino los tres binding del XAML 
En el (Code Behind) claro comento idProducto y no peta que es el formulario de creación que veis ahora

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IdVenta == 0)
            {
                using (Model.MiBaseEntities1 db = new Model.MiBaseEntities1())
                {
                    var oVenta = new Venta
                    {
                        IdProducto = int.Parse(txtIdProducto.Text),
                        Plataforma = txtPlataforma.Text,
                        Comprador = txtComprador.Text,
                        FechaVenta = DateTime.Parse(txtFechaVenta.Text),
                        Cantidad = int.Parse(txtCantidad.Text),
                        PrecioVenta = decimal.Parse(txtPrecioVenta.Text),
                        PrecioEnvio = decimal.Parse(txtPrecioEnvio.Text),
                        PrecioCompra = decimal.Parse(txtPrecioCompra.Text),
                        IngresoNeto = decimal.Parse(txtIngresoNeto.Text),
                        Nserie = txtNserie.Text,
                        Estado = txtEstado.Text,
                        Observación = txtObservación.Text,
                        Bloqueado = bool.Parse(txtBloqueado.Text)
                    };

                    db.Venta.Add(oVenta);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    MainWindow1.StaticMainFrame1.Content = new VentasLista();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (Model.MiBaseEntities1 db = new Model.MiBaseEntities1())
                {
                    var oVenta = db.Venta.Find(IdVenta);
                    oVenta.IdProducto = int.Parse(txtIdProducto.Text);
                    oVenta.Plataforma = txtPlataforma.Text;
                    oVenta.Comprador = txtComprador.Text;
                    oVenta.FechaVenta = DateTime.Parse(txtFechaVenta.Text);
                    oVenta.Cantidad = int.Parse(txtCantidad.Text);
                    oVenta.PrecioVenta = decimal.Parse(txtPrecioVenta.Text);
                    oVenta.PrecioEnvio = decimal.Parse(txtPrecioEnvio.Text);
                    oVenta.PrecioCompra = decimal.Parse(txtPrecioCompra.Text);
                    oVenta.IngresoNeto = decimal.Parse(txtIngresoNeto.Text);
                    oVenta.Nserie = txtNserie.Text;
                    oVenta.Estado = txtEstado.Text;
                    oVenta.Observación = txtObservación.Text;
                    oVenta.Bloqueado = bool.Parse(txtBloqueado.Text);

                    db.Entry(oVenta).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    MainWindow1.StaticMainFrame1.Content = new VentasLista();
                }
            }
        }
```

Puede ser que el error este en Model que me ha generado Sql Server no estoy seguro

```
    public partial class Venta
    {
        public int IdVenta { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdProducto { get; set; }
        public string Plataforma { get; set; }
        public string Comprador { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaVenta { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Cantidad { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PrecioEnvio { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PrecioVenta { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PrecioCompra { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> IngresoNeto { get; set; }
        public string Nserie { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public string Observación { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Bloqueado { get; set; }

        public virtual Producto Producto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda y acepto encantado cualquier mejora ya que estoy empezando con WPF. 
Un saludo
Rodri

Comment: Te pase una forma para tomar el valor del idProducto que necesitas, de todos modos tu titulo no coincide con tu problema, ya que necesitas tomar el valor del combobox de forma correcta y la base te da ese error porque no tomas el valor correcto.

Answer (score 0):

En tu clase Producto haria el override a `ToString()`

```
public class Producto
{
  public int IdProducto {get;set;}
  public string Articulo {get;set;}
  public string Compañia{get;set;}
  public string Modelo{get;set;}

  public override ToString()
  {
    return Articulo + " " + Compañia + " " + Modelo;
  } 
}
```

En tu comboxBox deberias rellenarlo con un `List<Producto>`, para tener el objeto completo.
Luego en tu boton cuando guardas, lo haces de la siguiente manera.

```
IdProducto = ((Producto)txtIdProducto.SelectedItem).IdProducto
```

De esta forma le hace Parse al item que tenes seleccionado en el `ComboBox` si le das click y no tenes nada seleccionado puede darte una excepcion. Para que eso no pase podes hacer asi:

```
var p = txtIdProducto.Selecteditem as Producto;
 if(p != null)
   {
     p.IdProducto; // si no es null la conversion se realizo bien y podes acceder al valor.
   }
```